# Adding inner join while update but filtering from the second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables - `slots` and `locations`

In the `slots` table i need to update `timeslot` column where `location_type` = 1
However, `location_type` is not in the `slot`.

Rather `slots` table has `location_id` a primary key from the `locations` table.

Understandably, `location_type` is in `locations_table`.

I've come up with this..by going through similar S/O answers:

```
update slots
set slots.timeslot = 0
from slots
inner join locations
on slots.location_id = locations.location_id
where locations.location_type = 1;
```

Here is my error:

```
MySQL said:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from slots
inner join locations
on slots.location_jd = locations.loc...' at line 3
```

I feel I am almost there, but am messing up something.
What is it that needs to be changed here?

Comment: You are using SQL Server syntax in MySQL.  That is why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no from clause for update statement

```
update slots
inner join locations
on slots.location_id = locations.location_id
set slots.timeslot = 0
where locations.location_type = 1
```